# How to add a index on a table column in TDengine?

Tags: tdengine

Does TDengine support index on a normal table column? I know TDengine has a timestamp index for the first column. I want to filter according to a normal table column efficiently. Can I add an index on that column?

Answer (score 0):

I think TDengine doesn't support index in 2.x versions. In later versions maybe inverted index will be added like ES.